# Get all property expressions from a type lambda expressions

Tags: c#, razor, lambda

I want to make a HtmlHelper that can produce hidden fields for all properties of a class.

In my razor page I will call the following:

```
@Html.HiddenForObject(x=>x.SomeClass)
```

where x would be the model defined with @model SomeOtherClass

My helper is defined as such =>

```
public static MvcHtmlString HiddenForObject<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
            Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
```

Now some class has a few public properties that I want to make hidden field for.
But here I am stuck
I need to find the right code to iterate over all the properties in my expression, get the expressions for those properties so I can call

```
//Pseudo code
foreach(var propertyExpression in expression) {
@Html.HiddenFor(expression);
}
```

I tried a few things but basically I ran out of ideas.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: well you could use reflection but... its not considered 'good'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection on expression

```
        foreach (var p in stage.GetType().GetProperties())
        {

        }
```

However, there would probably be a rather large performance hit if you did that, plus it could open a whole can of security worms, especially if you use your class to access the database as well.

You could extend the idea, though, and define some attributes to mark your hidden fields, and use your extension method to pick them out.

Comment: I will mark this as the correct answer, but due to the performance hit I've abandoned the idea and went for another aproach.